# Java. Как запретить изменение только ширины или только высоты окна?

Tags: java, view, окно

Так запретить, чтобы не было даже возможности изменить этот параметр. Если обрабатывать событие изменение размера, например, ширины, то появляется отвратительная анимация возвращения окна к исходному размеру.

Comment: Сделать окно полностью неизменяемым и написать свою реализацию.

Comment: Сделать минимальную и максимальную ширину окна равную одному значению.